# How to change Operator highlight color in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, iterm2, vim-syntax-highlighting

I just switched to iTerm2 on macOS and found some of its options go to Vim as well. That's the case for fonts, I was able to select a Vim font that I like from iTerm options.

It seems iTerm color options also apply to Vim highligh. But in this case highlight situation is not good enogh for my taste. So I tried to change:

```
:hi Comment ctermfg=gray
```

Changes font color of comments.

I would like to change `=`, `::`, `+`, `-` color, I think these are Operators, so I tried:

```
:hi Operator ctermfg=blue
```

But it seems nothing changes. How should I do that?

If it matters I'm playing with .cpp/.h files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=`,  `+`, `-`,  etc. are not  defined as  `Operator` in
the  default  C syntax,  which  C++  inherits from.  Usually
`Operator` means  keywords like  `sizeof`, `typeof`,  and so
on.

Since you describe your  terminal settings "leaking" to Vim,
it's very likely  that your colorscheme is  not defining the
`ctermfg` and  `bg`. Either for a  custom matched `Operator`
group  or for  `Normal`  (most likely).  You  can test  that
easily  by setting  `Normal`  to some  color,  like in  your
example:

```
:hi Normal ctermfg=blue
```

If the `+`  et all changes, sure they are  not in fact being
matched as  `Operator`. To fix  it, if you agree  on setting
your `Normal` group  color then that's all there is  to it —
`Normal`  is the  group for  default text,  unmatched syntax
elements. When your colorscheme does not set it, it will use
the terminal colors.

If however you want to have the operators in a different and
exclusive color,  you will  need to  match them  manually by
defining a new syntax item (`:h syn-define`).

Comment: Yes, `hi Normal ctermfg=blue` changes it all. But infact I would like to have the operators in a different and exclusive color, as you pointed in the end. I guess the syn match is the way to go. May I ask help on how to write the regexp?

Comment: I use this regex to match special characters: `syntax match   mySpecialSymbols "+\|-\|\*\|;\|?\|:\|,\|<\|>\|&\||\|!\|\~\|%\|=\|)\|(\|{\|}\|\.\|\[\|\]"`. The sequence `\|` is the "or", just add or remove characters as you need it.